# Does docfx support 'include' tag in triple-slash comments

Tags: docfx

I try to generate API documentation for project that has [include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/include) tags in triple-slash comments using [DocFX](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx).

Included content present in Visual Studio IntelliSense and in documentation that is generated by [SandCastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB), but it is missing in documentation produced by DocFX.

Does DocFX support `/// <include file='ExtDocs.xml' path='...some xpath...'/>` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

DocFX doesn't guarantee to support all the SandCastle syntax, and `include` is not supported for now.

The feature request to DocFX: https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/2328